# How to automatically group data based on a range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Given the below example, I have a data set, and I want the data set to be grouped by decrements of 5 in terms of x. How can I accomplish this?

Basically, I want to group my data set based on my x values being larger or smaller than a number.

[image: Example]

Comment: Do you actually need blank lines between groups or would another way or differentiating each group (ex: shading the cells) be OK?

Comment: Shading the cells would be ok.

Answer (score 0):

1. Let's define some names, to make formula writing smoother:
   [image]
   Note that I defined but didn't end up using a name called 'x' for column `A`.
2. Define your decrement value. This is set to 5 for the purposes of the example.
3. Formula to run the decrement value in column `F` against the first x:
   `=firstx+decrement*(ROW()-2)`
   That copies down. The group names in `G` you can write yourself
4. VLOOKUP in column C to assign your data to groups.
   `=VLOOKUP(firstx,groups,2,TRUE)`
   The TRUE flag is the key to use VLOOKUP to get the group assignment rather than an exact matching record.
5. You can use conditional formatting against column `C` or insert rows between data groups or otherwise manipulate as needed, now that you've grouped it formulaically.

Answer (score 0):

To alternate the shading of cells, use conditional formatting with the following formula:

```
=ROUND(($A$2-$A2)/10,0)=ROUNDDOWN(($A$2-$A2)/10,0)
```

Assumptions:

1) `x` is sorted in decreasing order as in your screen cap

2) The decrement of `5` is based on the maximum value of `x` (i.e. the first value of the column) again, as in your screen cap